# Creating more than one sitemap and relating it to a subdomain - will I be penalized?

Tags: seo, subdomain, sitemap, canonical-url

I'm thinking in creating a subdomain containing all the reviews from my products, for example: `http://reviews.mystore.com`

At this subdomain, I have my `sitemap.xml` pointing for the reviews page about my product. So `reviews.mystore.com/sitemap.xml` will be like:

```
<url>
  <loc>
    http://reviews.mystore.com/products/204/reviews
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2014-05-20T12:05:43-03:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

And my reviews page like: `http://reviews.mystore.com/products/204/reviews` will have a reference to my original product page like:

```
<meta content="http://mystore.com/products/my_cool_product" property="og:url">
<link href="http://mystore.com/products/my_cool_product" rel="canonical">
```

Notice to `content` and `href` pointing to the ORIGINAL product page.

Will doing this increase or decrease my rank?

Comment: It won't affect your rank. Those values will probably just be ignored since they are not on the domain the sitemap is for.

Comment: But what I described is that Yotpo does [here](http://support.yotpo.com/entries/23147482-Minisite-and-CNAME-help). So, this minisite will not help my site?

Comment: It won't add any seo value to your site.

Comment: Why it won't add any value? Do you have any reference?

Comment: John does not need one. He is right. Stop over thinking the SEO thing. SEO in not complicated unless you make it complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things incorrect here.

1. A canonical tag should only be implemented on pages that are [identical or vastly similar](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html). Your review page will not be vastly similar to your product page as it will have content from the reviews that (I presume) does not appear on the product page.
2. If a page is canonicalised too another page, then it should [not be included in a sitemap.xml fil](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)e. Only valid pages that you wish to be indexed should be included in sitemap.xml files, if a page has a canonical tag referencing another page you are telling Google you do not wish that page to be indexed.

From Google guidelines:

> Pick a canonical (preferred) URL for each of your pages, and tell us
>   about your preference by submitting these canonical URLs in a sitemap.

With the example you gave in the comments for grandslamnewyork.com you can see this is not having any effect.

In their sitemap they have [this review URL](http://reviews.grandslamnewyork.com/products/black-i-love-ny-tee-shirt/reviews/1), that has a canonical URL pointing to the [main product page](http://www.grandslamnewyork.com/products/Black-I-Love-NY-Tee-Shirt.html). If you pick one of the reviews lower down on the review URL (one that appears on the paginated pages of reviews on the main product page, which are loaded via java script so Google doesnt see them on the product page) and search for that exact content in Google nothing is indexed for it: [Click Here](https://www.google.com.au/search?num=100&es_sm=93&q=%22The%20quality%20of%20the%20merchandise%20and%20the%20speed%20of%20delivery%20were%20great.%22&oq=%22The%20quality%20of%20the%20merchandise%20and%20the%20speed%20of%20delivery%20were%20great.%22&gs_l=serp.3...4095.5042.0.5331.3.3.0.0.0.0.72.203.3.3.0.ekp,kpns=1000,kpnss=100...0...1.1.45.serp..3.0.0.4UbkLC2uO1E) and the review page itself is not indexed in Google either: [Click Here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22http://reviews.grandslamnewyork.com/products/black-i-love-ny-tee-shirt/reviews/1%22&oq=%22http://reviews.grandslamnewyork.com/products/black-i-love-ny-tee-shirt/reviews/1%22&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8meter%7Dsourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

So what does this show? To me it shows that what ever they are trying to do has no effect. The review pages don't get indexed as they have a canonical pointing to the main page, so this means the reviews that are loaded via the java script but appear on the reviews pages don't get indexed either. So as far as I can tell, this methord offers no SEO value what so ever.

Comment: About your point 1: I will have my reviews about the product in the products page, but showed by a dynamically generated widget.

About your point 2, I don't know if I going to suffer. The solution i've described is used [here](http://support.yotpo.com/entries/23147482-Minisite-and-CNAME-help) and I don't know if I'm going to increase by seo by using this tool like this

Comment: If the review pages are the same as the product pages then you can use a canonical tag on them. However this will not provide any SEO value at all, as you are telling Google to count the review pages as the same page as the product pages and when Google reads the canonical tag the review pages will eventually be removed from the SERPs. Point 2, you aren't doing the same as yotpo, as they are not defining canonical tags so they can put the URLs in a sitemap.xml. If you canonical a page to another page, it should not be defined in a sitemap.xml file. There is no SEO value in what you want to do.

Comment: Actually their sitemap  point to reviews page. [Here's](http://reviews.grandslamnewyork.com/sitemap.xml) a sitemap sample pointing to this [review](http://reviews.grandslamnewyork.com/products/ct-as-pink-hi-top-infant/reviews/1) page. Look at the source: There's a canonical reference to the original product page. They don't intend this review page to be seen by customers, but only for search engines. My greater doubt it's if this helps SEO

Comment: I have extended my main answer.